# How can I take a list and add elements in columns in intervals?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Here's my problem:
This is for an introductory Python course, however I just cannot wrap my head around how to do this without using loops. I have a list of lists, with each list containing 12 float values corresponding to sunshine hours in a month. Each list of 12 months corresponds to a year (1929 - 2009).
Here is an example of the list:

```
    data = [
[43.8, 60.5, 190.2, 144.7, 240.9, 210.3, 219.7, 176.3, 199.1, 109.2, 78.7, 67.0],
[49.9, 54.3, 109.7, 102.0, 134.5, 211.2, 174.1, 207.5, 108.2, 113.5, 68.7, 23.3],...]
```

Now, the task is to calculate mean sunshine hours per day in the winter. This is to be done by the following algorithm: Decade 1930-1939 would equal the hours from (Dec 1929 + Jan 1930 + Dec 1930 + Jan 1931...+ Jan 1939) / (20 numbers * 30 days in a month) = Mean winter sunshine hours per day.

Now I can do this using for loops, but the task is to do this using NO loops and instead using Numpy and array manipulation.

Here's things that I have considered:
-Splitting the data into two arrays (one with the January column and one with the December column)
-Adding those (though remember, there's an offset because Jan 1929 is unused as well as Dec 2009)
-Splitting the addition array into decades and averaging them.

However I'm very lost on how to go about this. So far I've split the data list into January and December arrays, but now I'm stuck.

Update: I've made an array with all the correct "winter" monthly hours (Dec+Jan) and now I just have to figure out how to find the mean of groups of 10 of them.

```
dataarray = np.array(data)
December = dataarray[:,11]
January = dataarray[:,0]
JanDec = np.zeros(80)
JanDec[:] = January[1:] + December[:-1]
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your updated question, to group the data into decades you can `reshape` your array and take the mean along the correct axis.

This assumes that the number of years you have is divisible by 10 (which it appears to be since you have an array of length 80).

So, as a small example, if you wanted to group `[3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1]` into chunks of 2, you could write:

```
>>> a = np.array([3, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1])
>>> a.reshape(-1, 2)
np.array([[3, 2],
          [5, 3],
          [2, 1]])
```

This gives you a 2D array - the groups you want to calculate the mean of are the rows. To take the mean across the rows you use `mean(axis=1)`, so you can write:

```
>>> a.reshape(-1, 2).mean(axis=1)
np.array([ 2.5 , 4.0 , 1.5 ])
```

Using this idea, you can quickly take the mean across decades in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the array is the right idea, but you can do it more simply by just calling from the array itself, I'll let you figure out how you could generalize but for this case -

```
arraydata=np.array(data)
winter=arraydata[:,::11]
average=np.mean(winter)/(20*30)
```

'winter' tells numpy to form a new array containing all data from every 11th column. Equally, you can choose which columns to pull with a similar approach for the first dimension of array data and sum it :-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help! However, do you know how I might be able to group it in 10s so I can produce an output per decade?

Comment: Unsure if you can do it if you have a number of years indivisible directly by 10, but if that's the case np.vsplit(winter, n) will return a list of arrays in decades, where n is the total number of years/10!

Read about np.vsplit 

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vsplit.html#numpy.vsplit

Comment: Another somewhat cheat offered by vsplit if n isn't divisible by 10 would be to enter them manually:

decades=np.vsplit(winter, np.array([10,20,30...]))